# Stubborn "Debug Assertion Failed" error in C++

Tags: c++

So I've scoured the internet trying to fix this problem but nothing seems to work. I'm a student taking a C++ class so excuse my ignorance.

As the title says I keep getting an error box that goes like this

"Debug assertion Failed!
Program: I:(filepath)

File: f:(filepath)
line: 52

Expression: (stream != NULL)"

I think it has something to do with the pointers, but I don't know...
My buddies have all used this exact code so I'm starting to think God hates me

Sorry if I did anything wrong in my question

Here's my code

```
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #define NROW 7
 #define NCOL 8
 #define FILEIN "input_practice.txt"
 #define FILEOUT "output_practice.txt"

 void GJ(double A[NROW][NCOL]);
 void pivot(double A[NROW][NCOL], int j);
 void norm (double A[NROW][NCOL], int j);
 void diag (double A[NROW][NCOL], int j);
 void swap(double *x, double *y);
 void main()
 {
//define variables
double A[NROW][NCOL]; 
int i, j;
FILE *filein_ptr;
FILE *fileout_ptr;

//open files
filein_ptr=fopen(FILEIN,"r");
fileout_ptr=fopen(FILEOUT,"w");

//get input from file
for (j=0; j<NROW; j++)
{
    for (i=0; i<NCOL; i++)
    {
    fscanf(filein_ptr,"%lf",&A[j][i]);
    }
}
//Run Gauss-Jordan
GJ(A);

//output
fprintf(fileout_ptr,"Solution Matrix:\n");
for (j=0; j<NROW; j++)
{
    for (i=0; i<NCOL; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fileout_ptr,"%lf",A[i][j]);
        fprintf(fileout_ptr," ");
    }
fprintf(fileout_ptr,"\n");
}

//close files
fclose(filein_ptr);
fclose(fileout_ptr);
}



void GJ(double A[NROW][NCOL])
{    //Run it
int j;
for (j=0;j<NROW;j++)
{
    pivot(A,j);
    norm(A,j);
    diag(A,j);
}
}
void pivot(double A[NROW][NCOL], int j)
{
int maxrow=j,i;
//find max values
for (i=j; i < NROW ; i++)
{
    if ( fabs(A[i][j]) > fabs(A[maxrow][j]))
    {   maxrow=i;
    }
}
if (maxrow != 0)
{
    for (i=j; i < NCOL; i++)
    {
        swap(&A[j][i],&A[maxrow][i]);
    } 
}
}


void norm (double A[NROW][NCOL], int j)
{   
//temp
double temp=A[j][j];
int i;
//Normalize
for(i=j; i < NCOL ; i++)
{   A[j][i] = (A[j][i] / temp);
}
}

void diag (double A[NROW][NCOL], int j)
{
//define
double temp;
int i,k;
//Diagonalize
for(i = 0; i < NROW; i++)
{
    if(i != j)
    {
        temp = A[i][j];
        for(k=j; k < NCOL; k++)
        {
            A[i][k]= A[i][k] - (temp * A[j][k]);
        }
    }
}
}
void swap(double *x, double *y)
{
//Swap
double z;
    z=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=z;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Can you strip it down to a minimal example?

Comment: Should  `fprintf(fileout_ptr,"%lf",A[i][j]);` be `fprintf(fileout_ptr,"%lf",A[j][i]);` in main?

Comment: ok so I think you were right, I changed my code up and now i dont get the debug assertion thing anymore.... but now i get this error message: "1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open I:\ME400\C++\Practice1\Debug\Practice1.exe for writing"    I have no idea what this means :(

Comment: Ok, so i figured it out... where i defined file in and file out I had the file names messed up. Newbie mistake

Answer (score 3):

That code is not the code that's asserting, simply because it has no assertions in it.

You may need to go at have a look at line 52 of the *actual* file causing the assertion and investigate from there.

Based on the (presumably modified by you to protect file names) assertion output:

```
"Debug assertion Failed! Program: I:(filepath)

File: f:(filepath)
line: 52

Expression: (stream != NULL)"
```

you'll be able to track down the issue. It may be that you've failed to open the stream, it may be that the file didn't exist where you expected and you didn't check for errors. It may even be that you've overwritten the stream variable with a buffer overflow problem.

The most likely case in my opinion is that the file didn't open properly because your code is running in a different directory from where the file is. You should really check the return values from `fopen()` to catch this.

Comment: Wrong; the assertion is probably in library code, for which he might not even have source. That file is not "causing" the assertion. The caller is causing the assertion. The module with the assertion is just defending the interface contract.

Comment: @Kaz, there's nothing "wrong" in my answer. I stated that the file shown isn't the one failing. That doesn't mean it's not the **root** cause of the problem, just that it's not the one asserting. The final paragraph covers the most likely case in the event it's a library assertion.

Comment: You are wrong; the code shown is in fact what is failing. Passing a null pointer to a standard library function like `fprintf` is a failure: it violates the contract. Any subsequent crash is not that function's fault. It is not causing anything.

Comment: @Kaz, we're going to have to disagree on a semantic issue here. The library code (if that's what's actually doing it) _is_ causing the assertion and that's the best place to look as to why. It may be doing it because the code shown broke the rules but that's why I used the phrase root cause in my previous comment. I'll modify the answer to remove the ambiguity between failing and asserting.

Answer (score 1):

Your program neglects to handle the possible, and very likely errors from the `fopen` function, which returns a null pointer if it cannot open a file.

What happens if `input_practice.txt` doesn't exist, or is not readable to you (no permissions)? What if you don't have the permissions to overwrite or create `output_practice.txt`?

The abort is happening in some library function which is defending itself against being passed a null pointer.

Passing null pointers to certain standard C library functions is undefined behavior, so they are allowed to loudly diagnose the situation.

Comment: I figured it out and got it running, thanks for the help! You were right in saying my files didnt exist.. had the names wrong

Comment: @user3610591 It's usually best to write the extra code to detect these situations, even in small programs like this.

Comment: @user3610591 Well i'm glad my answer was helpful in some what. I hope the combined efforts here were able to get your issue fixed. Sometimes your errors are the smallest things like file names rather than a big error in code.

Comment: There are two kinds of conditions which are both informally called "errors": unwanted situations in the environment (disk full, file not found, host unreachable, ...) and run-time errors having to do with incorrect operations or incorrect data caused by a bug in the program. (Sometimes these are called "internal errors").  We have to catch the environmental situations. The two errors can be linked as you can see; by not checking the environmental situation you end up with a null pointer, which the library regards as incorrect data: an internal error.

Comment: @Kaz I'm just taking an intro course to VBA and C++ so I don't know much, but what would that extra code be?  Might be useful for my final coming up!

Comment: @AlexZywicki Yep, i found that out quickly. It's probably the most frustrating thing i have ever done... but at the same time it feels soooooo good to have my program run.

Comment: You have to think about the requirements first. "What should be the program's behavior if this file is not found". Once you know the requirements, then you think about "how do I design the code to handle this situation in the required way". Then code it!  E.g. the requirement could be "if the input file is not found, the program shall terminate with an informative message".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix your code specifically but i can try and give you a better idea what your error says.

An assertion is a test to see if a condition is try much like an `if()` statement but instead of executing a piece of code when it is true if will throw an exception when the condition is false.

So the code `assert(true==false)` would throw and exception because `true!=false`.

So `assert(stream != NULL)` would be the test you are failing in code.

To me this error would mean that you are trying to open a stream of some sort (from the looks of your code a file stream) but it is not being opened properly and then you are trying to use a stream that is not open to do something.

I apologize that i could not give a you a line number on where your code is broken but I hope my answer can help even a little.

Good luck

Comment: Although this didnt help with my problem i learned a bit. Thanks!